# What is the equivalent of BinaryReader.ReadString from C# to Flutter/Dart?

Tags: c#, flutter, file, binary, reader

I need to read the binary file list of string that are written using C# BinaryWriter.Write(text);

How we can read this in the side of Dart code...
[binaryreader.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binaryreader.cs)
[binarywriter.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binarywriter.cs)

BinaryReader.ReadString() from C# to Flutter/Dart.

BinaryReader.ReadString() in C# will auto advance the position after reading each string. that are saved in binary.

Comment: If you read the source code (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6d6fbe065e26c03177c49ace22dd45d5a0ae2551/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/BinaryWriter.cs#L346) you can see how the string is encoded in binary.